# Copy a parented object and paste it inside the parent without duplicating the parent

Tags: objects

Let's say that I have a cube, gave it a light object, set the cube as the parent of said light.
Now I want to copy the light 6 times and place it on all 6 sides of said cube.
When I only selected the light in the scene view and, copied it and pasted it 5 times, I ended up getting 5 additional cubes with the one light.

My question is essentially how I can only copy the light and paste it without pasting the parent, like a "child only copy and paste". That they all are children of the cube, without additional cubes or something like that.

Yes, of course, I can just set the newly pasted lights without a parent and then select the first cube as their parent and delete the 5 other cubes. But this feels a bit unnecessarily slow, especially when I want to have hundreds of children.

Do you know of any kind of way to do the " child only copy and paste " idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to get more copies of objects in Blender is not copying and pasting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but duplicating with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> if you want to link the data between the duplicates, as Martynas mentions in his answer. So his answer is complete and correct and you should accept that, I just wanted to additionally explain an advantage the *Duplicate* tool in Blender has over copy+paste.

Duplicating also allows you immediate movement (even on a constrained axis) or rotating or scaling when you create the duplicate, whereas copy and paste simply gets a copy in the same spot. This way you can very simply replicate the duplification and movement multiple times with *Edit* > *Repeat Last*, shortcut  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:

For example, you select a cube and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it. While the duplicate is still hovering under your mouse cursor and you did nothing to confirm the action, you could now enter <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, then <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> and the duplicate would have been moved 5 m on the X axis.

And now you can repeat this action with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and automatically get another cube 5 m away of the second cube in X direction. And repeat it over and over again to create a long row of cubes.

Instead of moving you could also rotate or scale the duplicate, you just have to press <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> to switch from translation to rotation or scaling.

With copy+paste this repeating action would not be possible, since <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> only repeats **one** last action. And while the transformations are done while duplicating this is seen as one action. Copying and object and then pasting it results in pasting as the last action. Repeating now would only repeat pasting an object. Moving and object after pasting it will make the movement the last action, so only moving the object will be repeated, but it will be the one you pasted, not a new one.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that copying and pasting copies all data related to the object so it creates possibly unwanted copies of materials, textures, particle systems data, parent objects and what not, while duplicating takes care of all connections to the stuff already existing in the scene which is in most cases the more desired result.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Yes right, but I guess the user partly already realized this, since this is what made him ask if there is a way to copy just the desired object without the connected stuff ;)

Comment: Thank you, that solved it!

Answer (score 3):

There is not much to it. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for duplicate or  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for duplicate linked so the copy shares data with the original.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it!